# Make text size change dynamically in table on aspx site

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, text-size

I´m making a simple website to display information from XML file that is created from information read from a server. Problem is that if user inserts information onto the server which is too long then the site alters. I was wondering if I could use JQuery and CSS to make the text in a certain cells smaller if it exceeds certain number of characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not make the text smaller.  Depending on the amount, you could make it so small that no one could read it.

Why not wrap the content in a `div`, set that `div`'s `height` and `width` to match whatever you want the `table` cell to be.  Then set the `div` to `overflow-y:scroll;`.

That way the text size won't change and the content will be usable no matter what the size.

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zpZXD/